# How to obtain a correct type when returning Template<T?> from a static function with null

Tags: generics, rx-java, kotlin

I'm trying some Rx and Kotlin.
Suppose I have a function that returns `Observable<T?>`:

```
public fun get():Observable<T?> {
    return if (someCondition()) {
        Observable.just(someLocalVarOfTypeT)
    } else {
        Observable.just(null)        
    }
}
```

The compiler can't infer `Observable.just(null)` because it substitutes `kotlin.Nothing` as `T` in this expression:

```
Type mismatch: required rx.Observable<T?> found rx.Observable<kotlin.Nothing?>
```

Trying to cast:

```
Observable.just(null as T)
```

leads to:

```
The cast will never succeed
```

The signature of `Observable.just(null)` is (for convenience):

```
public final static <T> Observable<T> just(final T value) {
    return ...
}
```

What is the correct way to cast such an `Observable` to the correct type?
Intermediate variable:

```
val a: Observable<T?> = Observable.just(null)
```

works, but looks weird...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest workaround is to explicitly specify generic argument:

```
public fun get(): Observable<T?> {
    return if (someCondition()) {
        Observable.just(someLocalVarOfTypeT)
    } else {
        Observable.just<T>(null)        
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to use `<T?>` instead of `<T>` on that `just()` call?

Answer (score 4):

Would `Observable.just(null as T?)` work?

Your original cast will never work because `T` is a non-nullable type, so null can't be cast to it. So casting it to a nullable `T` (aka `T?`) should work.